# How to block view access to folder on my server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

im using LAMP on Ubuntu 13.04.

Im using my server for databases using mysql.
The server is for android application, my app is a kind of soical network and i need to access my DB to get info.

Im connection to mysql with PHP.

Im storing my PHP scripts on /var/www folder.

My problem is that if i enter my IP address in my browser i can see all the files on that folder.

How can i make this files access able from the android application but blocked when using browser?

Thank for helping.

Comment: You need to clarify what you really need. Do you mean disable files indexing by apache?

Comment: I mean that if some user enter to my IP address he cannoy my files

Answer (score 0):

Create an `.htaccess` file and put this in it

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Only this line? what this line do?

Comment: it tells Apache to not display folder indexes when viewing a folder that does not have a default index file such as index.php or index.html